# How to make the second address field required on checkout page on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, javascript, validation, custom-field

Magento 2 has a option to extend the address field up to 4 fields.

This configuration can be found at:

> Store->Configuration->Customer->Customer Configuration->Name and
>   Address Option

and there is a tab called Number of Lines in a Street Address.

Now all I want is to make the second field required like how the first field is required by default.

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Quick Solution will be : u can go to `eav_attribute` table & make it required true

Comment: is  not any option to make the additional filed required form that table

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem?

Answer (score 6):

Note that this form in the checkout is built with JavaScript / UI Components, so the solution provided by @Abhinav does not apply here (even though you should make those address fields on those other pages required as well).

The proper solution (for the checkout scenario) is to write a plugin for the layout processor and handle it from there:

In `etc/frontend/di.xml`:

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor">
    <plugin name="my_custom_checkout" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor"/>
</type>
```

In `Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor.php`:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout;

use Magento\Framework\Stdlib\ArrayManager;

/**
 * Class DirectoryDataProcessor
 * @package Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout
 */
class DirectoryDataProcessor
{
    /**
     * @var ArrayManager
     */
    protected $arrayManager;

    /**
     * LayoutProcessor constructor.
     * @param ArrayManager $arrayManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        ArrayManager $arrayManager
    ) {
        $this->arrayManager = $arrayManager;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor $subject
     * @param array $jsLayout
     * @return array
     */
    public function afterProcess(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor $subject, array $jsLayout)
    {
        $path = $this->arrayManager->findPath('street', $jsLayout);

        $streetNode = $this->arrayManager->get($path, $jsLayout);
        foreach ($streetNode['children'] as $idx => &$child) {
            // Make all address fields required:
            if (!isset($child['validation']['required-entry'])) {
                $child['validation']['required-entry'] = true;
            }
        }

        $jsLayout = $this->arrayManager->set($path, $jsLayout, $streetNode);

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, it's working perfectly. Same way how to make **State** field mandatory?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.4.1. and this solution does not seem to be working.
`Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Plugin class Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\DirectoryDataProcessor doesn't exist`

Answer (score 1):

Override the template

```
design\frontend\magento_customer\view\frontend\templates\address

<div class="field additional">
    <label class="label" for="street_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_i+1 ?>">
        <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address %1', $_i+1) ?></span>
    </label>
    <div class="control">
        <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getStreetLine($_i+1)) ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Street Address %1', $_i+1) ?>" id="street_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_i+1 ?>" class="input-text <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ if($_i == 2){ echo "required-entry ".$_streetValidationClass} else{ echo $_streetValidationClass; } ?>">
    </div>
</div>
```