# Validation on checkout Page in Address Field

Tags: magento2

i want to Create validation that customer cannot checkout if they Input PO BOX/Parcel Lockers on address
field how can i achieve this??

Comment: This question has already been answered: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/169581/how-to-make-the-second-address-field-required-on-checkout-page-on-magento-2

Comment: i want input validation how can i check if some one put input PO BOX/Parcel Lockers